# Convert a System.Drawing.Bitmap to Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, azure-cognitive-services

I have a WPF project and captured an image from a usb camera to a System.Drawing.Bitmap (I also can capture System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource) and need to convert it to a  Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap to make a "VideoFrame" to compare to an Onnx model.

The camera driver is a .net assembly and will not bind to a uwp project. I've tried creating a .net standard assembly to bridge the gap with no success. I simply need a bitmap converted to a SoftwareBitmap. Please help!

I'm using this code for the basis of the compassion of the Bitmap image from the camera - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-onnx12-customvision-sample

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct conversion. You'll need to extract the image data from the System.Drawing.Bitmap and then create the new SoftwareBitmap from that data.

For example, you could use [Save(Stream, ImageFormat)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_IO_Stream_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_) method to save this image to the specified stream in the specified format.

Then, you could try to call [BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.createasync) method to create the decoder from the stream.

After that you could call [GetSoftwareBitmapAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.getsoftwarebitmapasync) to get a SoftwareBitmap object.

The following is a simple code sample:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getyourbitmap();
using (var stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(stream.AsStream(),ImageFormat.Jpeg);//choose the specific image format by your own bitmap source
    Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
    SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error 'InMemoryRandomAccessStream' does not contain a definition for 'AsStream' . I looks like the - Save (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)  is only the System.IO.Stream.

Comment: @EricPhillips `AsStream` is an extension method in 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime'. See [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#Ydhx0HKZfSd1lUpP.97) to add reference to it. According to that blog, an easy way is installing the 'UwpDesktop' nuget package for your WPF application, then it will automatically add reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use Windows.Security.Cryptography to create a IBuffer from the image array bytes. Then you can copy the IBuffer to the SoftwareBitmap.

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;

IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(ImageByteArray);

SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8, 800, 600);
softwareBitmap.CopyFromBuffer(buffer);
VideoFrame inputImage = VideoFrame.CreateWithSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```cs
Bitmap bitmap = ...;
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
}

var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
var bitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
```